# Erro Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, biblioteca

Estou tentando usar a biblioteca Commons Email, mas esta dando o seguinte erro

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
  at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1469)
  at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1496)
  at bibliotecaemail.UsandoBibliotecaDeEmail.main(UsandoBibliotecaDeEmail.java:21)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt
534-5.7.14 VYOHsiOCZ3lbdXJC3x-IYbSRirT9gsPyMC7T9gcBiL1LOm_HoPBk14WiBYh3uEioDQ9zI
534-5.7.14 PONsU-hvsTPui5RIjYcA5hbdGrtpMxnHbZ63pMfNHMKrZCV4MWOYhvlJdbShJg71>
534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 a15sm5631279qkl.20 - gsmtp

  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:965)
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:876)
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:780)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
  at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
  at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1459)
  ... 2 more
```

Segue aqui meu código: (ocultei a senha e o e-mail por segurança)

```
package bibliotecaemail;
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.Email;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;

public class UsandoBibliotecaDeEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws EmailException {

        Email email = new SimpleEmail();
        email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
        email.setSmtpPort(465);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("email@gmail.com", "********"));
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
        email.setFrom("brunojramosr@gmail.com");
        email.setSubject("Aula sobre uso de bibliotecas de terceiros");
        email.setMsg("Se etiver vendo este e-mail é porque o envio funcionou!");
        email.addTo("email2@gmail.com");
        email.send();
        System.out.println("E-mail enviado!");

    }
}
```

OBS: Já ativei o acesso à apps menso seguros e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Aqui eu configuro uma propriedade "mail.smtp.auth" como "true", mas é usando o javamail

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o que é. No gmail tem que habilitar o "senhas de app". Ele gera uma senha de 16 dígitos, ela fica padrão para inserir no código.

Aqui está a orientação > https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=pt-BR

Comment: Estranho... Não teria necessidade se você tivesse ativado a opção de apps menos seguros. Mas que bom que deu certo!